# check if network drive exists with timeout in c#

Tags: c#, exception, timeout, network-drive

i created a windows service that move files around between the server's hard drive (where the service is installed) to the network drive mapped in the server. one of the problems I encountered while creating a solution was network problems.

how do i check if a network drive exists while setting a timeout in checking it? If it times out, I catch the exception and retry in X number of minutes and leave items in queue.

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the call in a seperate thread and close the thread after a certain timeout. The following link implements a timeout logic for a method:

http://kossovsky.net/index.php/2009/07/csharp-how-to-limit-method-execution-time/

**EDIT**

One of the comments on the topic above suggest a better implementation using .NET Async Pattern:

```
public static T SafeLimex<T>(Func<T> F, int Timeout, out bool Completed)   
   {
       var iar = F.BeginInvoke(null, new object());
       if (iar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(Timeout))
       {
           Completed = true;
           return F.EndInvoke(iar);
       }
         F.EndInvoke(iar);
         Completed = false;
       return default(T);
   }
```

Comment: Not calling EndInvoke() is a pretty nasty memory leak.  Takes 10 minutes to recover.

Comment: If you use the following anonymous expression, it breaks what's trying to be accomplished here. 
SafeLimex(() => { Console.WriteLine("TEST"); Thread.Sleep(10000); Console.WriteLine("See, it still runs!"); }, 500, out testbool);

Answer (score 0):

As far as I recall, using the normal `System.IO` methods do the trick. So in this case, you'd simply use:

```
if (Directory.Exists("Z:\\MyNetworkFolder"))
{
    // Gogogo
}
else
{
    Thread.Sleep(MyTimeout);
}
```

If the folder does not exist, pause for whatever timeout you choose. This should do the job perfectly.

Comment: I believe this is NOT what @martin asked for.