# How to estimate method execution time?

Tags: c#, callback, execution-time

I have requirement to cancel method execution if it takes the more than two seconds to complete and restart it on another thread.

So, is there any way/call back mechanism/HACK, I can make method inform me that it crossed 2 seconds time limit?

Comment: Why don't you start it on another thread from the beginning?

Comment: I honestly don't think there's any easy way to *precisely* do what you are asking for. You would need to have hooks inserted all over the place. Why are you insistent on first invoking the method on the calling thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[check if network drive exists with timeout in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720862/check-if-network-drive-exists-with-timeout-in-c/)
https://web.archive.org/web/20140222210133/http://kossovsky.net/index.php/2009/07/csharp-how-to-limit-method-execution-time

**Async Pattern:**

```
public static T SafeLimex<T>(Func<T> F, int Timeout, out bool Completed)   
   {
       var iar = F.BeginInvoke(null, new object());
       if (iar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(Timeout))
       {
           Completed = true;
           return F.EndInvoke(iar);
       }
         F.EndInvoke(iar); //not calling EndInvoke will result in a memory leak
         Completed = false;
       return default(T);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create System.Threading.Timer on two seconds, and run your method in another thread and wait for callback from it, if method completes before timer runs you should dispose timer, otherwise you should abort thread in which you method are executing. This is pretty simple for example

```
using (new Timer(BreakFunction, true, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), Timeout.Infinite))
                    {
                        //TODO:here you should create another thread that will run your method
                    }
```

In BreakFunction you should abort thread that runs your methods

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if you can find it. I've been looking for it too.

What I usually do is start the method in another `Thread`, and start a `Timer` with 2 seconds in this case. The first time it raises the event, just do:

```
if (a.IsAlive)
{
   a.Abort();
}
```

Two important things:

- The `Thread` declared should be visible by the method that handles the timer
- When calling `Abort()`, it raises [ThreadAbortException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx), so you should correctly handle it in the method.